# If I know the variance of two numbers, is it possible to find their difference?

Tags: statistics, variance

If I know the variance of two numbers, is it possible to find their difference?

As in, the only information I have is the variance and that there are only two numbers.

How could I work backwards to find out what the difference between the two numbers is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the two numbers be $a$ and $b$. Then the variance is $$\sigma^2=\frac{(a^2+b^2)-\frac{(a+b)^2}{2}}{2-1}=\frac{(a-b)^2}2$$ so the difference is $$a-b=\sqrt{2\sigma^2}$$

Comment: Why use sample variance instead of population variance?

Comment: Corrected......

Comment: Isn't it the population variance $\mathrm{var}(X) = E[X^2] - E[X]^2$, so we have two in the denominator of both fractions.  I think the population variance should be chosen because we have only two numbers, so the "population size" is two.

Comment: See [this](http://statisticslectures.com/topics/variancepopulation/). Statistics is not really my strongest point.

Comment: Nvm, I upvoted.  To err is human.

Answer (score 1):

For perspective (make it an extended comment), the formulas come from:

$$\begin{align}\text{Var}(X) &= \mathbb E\left(X^2 \right)\quad-\quad \left[\;\mathbb E\left(X\right)\;\right]^2\\[2ex]
&=\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}{n}  \quad-\quad \left[  \frac{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{n}\right]^2
\end{align}.$$

When working with a sample we apply the [Bessel's correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_correction):

$$\begin{align}S^2 &=
\frac{n}{n-1}\,\left(\, \frac{\sum_{1}^n x_i^2}{n}  -\left[  \frac{\sum_{1}^n x_i}{n}\right]^2\right)\\[2ex]
&=
 \,\frac{n\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2  -\left[ \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n  x_i\right]^2}{(n-1)\,n}
\end{align}$$